# Porque cuando exportar un archivo excel en php algunas de las filas de datos sale corrida por el ejemplo lo que debe salir en A1 sale en la celda A2

Tags: php

```
$result123 = mysql_query($sql123);


    $filename = 'CFN por resolver'; //your file name
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('imagenes/logo.jpg');


    // Rename 2nd sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('CFN por resolver');
    /*********************Add column headings START**********************/
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('O8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('P8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q8', 'titulo');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('R8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('S8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('T8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('U8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('V8', 'titulo'); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('W8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('X8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Y8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Z8', 'titulo');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AA8', 'titulo');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AB8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AC8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AD8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AE8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AF8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AG8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AH8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AI8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AJ8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AK8', 'titulo');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AL8', 'titulo');

    $row = 9; // 1-based index
    while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result123)) {
        $col = 1;
        foreach($row_data as $key=>$value) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
            $col++;
        }
        $row++;
    }

    foreach(range('B','V') as $columnID) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setWidth(40);
    }

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B7:V8')->getFont()->setBold(true); //Make heading font bold


    /*********************Add color to heading START**********************/

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->getStyle('B8:AL8')
                ->getFill()
                ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
                ->getStartColor()
                ->setARGB('99ff99');
    /*********************Add color to heading END***********************/

    $objDrawing5 = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
    $objDrawing5->setName('Sample image');
    $objDrawing5->setDescription('Sample image');
    $objDrawing5->setImageResource($gdImage);
    $objDrawing5->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
    $objDrawing5->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
    $objDrawing5->setHeight(70);
    $objDrawing5->setCoordinates('A1');
    $objDrawing5->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=$filename.xls");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

?>

Comment: ¿Son saltos de fila o saltos de celda? No es lo mismo.

Comment: saltos de celda se corren para el lado pero solo ciertas columanas